# How to get middlewares from getDefaultMiddleware without deprecation message

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using a different setup for initializing the redux store (I don't want to use the configureStore method from redux-toolkit) for the purpose of injecting reducers on runtime.

```
import {
 createStore,
 combineReducers,
 applyMiddleware,
 createImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware,
 } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension";
import { createCustomMiddleWare} from "./myCustomMiddleWare"; 

const staticReducers = {};

const middlewares = [
createImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware(),
createCustomMiddleWare(),
];

const createReducer = (asyncReducers = {}) =>
combineReducers({
 ...staticReducers,
 ...asyncReducers,
});

export const initializeStore = (initializeState = {}) => {
  const store = createStore(
  createReducer(),
  initializeState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
  store.asyncReducers = {};
  store.injectReducer = (key, reducer) => {
  store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer;
  store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
  return store;
  };
  return store;
};

export default initializeStore;
```

I was wondering wether there is a way to add Thunk middleware from redux-toolkit (without installing the redux-thunk package seperately)

I tried using the getDefaultMiddleware() method from redux-toolkit which imports three default middlewares that ships with redux-toolkit including thunk, but since I'm not using it as paramether for the configureStore's middleware callback, I get this error that getDefaultMiddleware is deprecated.

I was able to import one of the default middlewares by using createImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware() function that I found in the official documentations but I could not find a way to import thunk or serlizied middlewares (two other default middlewares of redux-toolkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be to use `configureStore` and using the `middleware` callback option.

There is really no good reason that would be using `createStore` here, that could come down to

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createReducer(),
  preloadedState: initializeState,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(createCustomMiddleWare())
})
```

Comment: what if I want to add multiple middlewares and not just logger, will there be multiple .concat() per middleware?

Comment: yes you can do that.